# Multiple radio button are getting selected in Android studio

Tags: java, android, xml

I created a form in Android studio. There is a gender selection option of 2 radio buttons. But when I run the app and select the radio buttons, both the buttons are getting selected at the same time.I tried it in various ways, but it's still giving me the same issue. If I try to give android:onClick on the RadioButton in XML, the app just keeps crashing.

This is my XML code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:background="#FFFFFF">

<ImageView

    android:id="@+id/userInfoBackgroundImageView"

    android:layout_width="0dp"

    android:layout_height="0dp"

    android:scaleType="centerCrop"

    android:src="@drawable/money4"

    android:contentDescription="@string/user_info_background_description"

    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

<View

    android:id="@+id/userInfoOverlayView"

    android:layout_width="0dp"

    android:layout_height="0dp"

    android:background="#80000000"

    android:contentDescription="@string/user_info_overlay_description"

    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

    android:id="@+id/userInfoCardView"

    android:layout_width="300dp"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_margin="16dp"

    android:background="#FFFFFF"

    android:elevation="8dp"

    android:radius="8dp"

    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"

    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="@color/form_bg"

        android:padding="15dp">

        <EditText

            android:id="@+id/etUserName"

            android:layout_width="0dp"

            android:layout_height="48dp"

            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"

            android:fontFamily="@font/loboster_font"

            android:hint="@string/hint_enter_name"

            android:inputType="textPersonName"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <RadioGroup

            android:id="@+id/radioGroupGender"

            android:layout_width="0dp"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/etUserName">

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <!-- RadioButton for Male -->

                <RadioButton

                    android:id="@+id/rbMale"

                    android:layout_width="0dp"

                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:text="Male"

                    android:fontFamily="@font/loboster_font"

                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <!-- RadioButton for Female -->

                <RadioButton

                    android:id="@+id/rbFemale"

                    android:layout_width="0dp"

                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:text="Female"

                    android:fontFamily="@font/loboster_font"

                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RadioGroup>

        <Button

            android:id="@+id/btnNext"

            android:layout_width="0dp"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"

            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"

            android:onClick="onNextButtonClick"

            android:fontFamily="@font/paytone_one_font"

            android:text="@string/next_button_text"

            android:textColor="@color/button_text_color"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/radioGroupGender" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

`

And Here is my JAVA code:

```
`public class NameGenderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText etName;
private RadioGroup rgGender;
private Button btnNext;

RadioButton radioButton;

String name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_name_gender);

    etName = findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
    rgGender = findViewById(R.id.radioGroupGender);
    btnNext = findViewById(R.id.btnNext);

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Retrieve the entered name
            name = etName.getText().toString().trim();

            // Validate the name
            if (name.isEmpty()) {
                etName.setError("Please enter your name");
                return;
            }
            int selectedRadioButtonId = rgGender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            if (selectedRadioButtonId == -1) {
                Toast.makeText(NameGenderActivity.this, "Please select your Gender", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
                radioButton = findViewById(selectedRadioButtonId);
                String gender = radioButton.getText().toString();
            startActivity(new Intent(NameGenderActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
            finish();

        }
    });

    rgGender.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // Handle radio button selection changes here
            radioButton = findViewById(checkedId);
            Toast.makeText(NameGenderActivity.this, "Selected button: " + radioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("chk", "Checkeit");
        }
    });
}
```

}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every `RadioButton` should be a child of `RadioGroup`, remove you additional `LinearLayout`

also you should have `return;` inside `if (selectedRadioButtonId == -1) {`, as currently probably you are always getting this result - `RadioGroup` does not see its children (`getCheckedRadioButtonId()`), as they are hidden inside yet another container (`LinearLayout`)

note that [`RadioGroup`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup) already is/extends `LinearLayout`, so you can set same params for it (also `android:orientation`)

```
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroupGender"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/etUserName">

            <!-- RadioButton for Male -->
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbMale"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Male"
                android:fontFamily="@font/loboster_font"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <!-- RadioButton for Female -->
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbFemale"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Female"
                android:fontFamily="@font/loboster_font"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </RadioGroup>
```